# Strange error in Android Studio - why unresolved?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was developing my project with my project.
But unfortunately, the system was reset several times.
Now the contents of some files are messed up.
Some methods are also not recognized.

Even with the construction of a new project there are problems.
please guide me

```
 val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.home)
// or this one
cal.time = Date(stringDate.toLong())
```

Android Studio seems to be having trouble code completion

**Fixed**

Another interesting point is that the project is running and running, but Imam is having trouble in the Android studio environment. The following steps are also performed.

Android Studio 3.1: Erroneous unresolved references in editor

Comment: have you tried reinstalling android studio ?

Comment: Try the invalidate cache and restart option